# Custom new field in Woocommerce checkout does not work for consecutive orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, checkout

I am having hard times with a custom checkout field which works when aded at the first order, but doesn't appear in consecutive orders made by the same customer.

In a nutshell, I have a custom field which is a card number. At the customer registration, it is asked if the customer wants to get a shopping card. If the customer flags the option, a field with "y" is added to the user_meta table. Then the shop owner will send via email to teh customer the card number.

At the first order made by the customer, in teh checkout page a card_number custom field appears: the customer has to add the card number obtained by the shop. The order appears then with the card number (it works) and the card number is saved in the user_meta table as well.

Here follows the code I used for the checkout procedure:

```
/**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */

add_action ('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'checkout_w55_card_number' );

function checkout_w55_card_number( $checkout ) {

    //extracts the value of the w55_card_number field
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $w55_card = '';
    if ($user_id)
    {
        //extracts the value of the w55_card_number field
    $w55_card = get_user_meta($user_id, 'w55_card_number', true);
    }
    //condition is the w55_card_number field is empty or not
    if ( !empty($w55_card) ) :  echo '<div id="checkout_w55_card_number"><h2>' . __('N. tessera W55') . '</h2><div style="padding:15px; background-color: #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #efccb9"><p>' .$w55_card . '</p></div></div>'; 
    else :

          echo '<div id="checkout_w55_card_number"><h2>' . __('N. tessera W55') . '</h2>';

          woocommerce_form_field( 'w55_card_number', array(
              'type'          => 'text',
              'class'         => array('w55-card-number-class form-row-wide'),
              'label'         => __('Inserisci n. tessera W55'),
              'placeholder'   => __('Inserisci numero'),
              ), $checkout->get_value( 'w55_card_number' ));
          echo '</div>';
    endif;
}
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'w55_card_number_update_order_meta' );

function w55_card_number_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $w55_card = '';
    if ($user_id)
    {
        //extracts the value of the w55_card_number field
    $w55_card = get_user_meta($user_id, 'w55_card_number', true);
    }   

    if ( !empty( $_POST['w55_card_number'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'w55_card_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['w55_card_number'] ) );
    }

}
/**
 * Update the user meta with W55 number if filled
 */
function w55_card_number_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta( $customer_id) {
    if (! empty( $_POST['w55_card_number'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'w55_card_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['w55_card_number']));
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'w55_card_number_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 2 );


/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'w55_card_number_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function w55_card_number_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('w55_card_number').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'w55_card_number', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

As I said before, everything works fine for the first order. However a PROBLEM EXISTS when the same customer goes back to the online shop and buys something else. At the point in the checkout field the card number appears, but IT IS NO MORE SAVED in the new order (post_meta table): in few words the code to update the order meta with the field value doesn't work anymore. Since it is not saved there, it doesn't appear in the order edit page, as well as in the order email.

I suppose that the code I wrote in the "update order meta" section takes only value which arrive through $_POST. Hence  I tried to add the following condition which should take the value from the user_id meta table, but still it doesn't work.

```
/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'w55_card_number_update_order_meta' );

function w55_card_number_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $w55_card = '';
    if ($user_id)
    {
        //extracts the value of the w55_card_number field
    $w55_card = get_user_meta($user_id, 'w55_card_number', true);
    }   

    if ( !empty( $_POST['w55_card_number'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'w55_card_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['w55_card_number'] ) );
    }
    elseif ( !empty ($card_number) )
    {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'w55_card_number', $card_number, false );
    }
}
```

Any kind suggestion? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem. If this may be of help to someone else, I hereby explain what I did.

Actually my field w55_card_number was coming in a simple `<p>` tag, thus it could not be possible to extrapolate it. I created an `<input>` field and everything worked fine

I substituted the following line

```
//condition is the w55_card_number field is empty or not
    if ( !empty($w55_card) ) :  echo '<div id="checkout_w55_card_number"><h2>' . __('N. tessera W55') . '</h2><div style="padding:15px; background-color: #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #efccb9"><p>' .$w55_card . '</p></div></div>';
```

with this line

```
//condition is the w55_card_number field is empty or not
    if ( !empty($w55_card) ) :  

    echo '<div id="checkout_w55_card_number"><h2>' . __('N. tessera W55') . '</h2><div style="padding:15px; background-color: #FCFCFC; border: 1px solid #efccb9"><input type="text" class= "input-w55_card_number" name="w55_card_number" id = "w55_card_number" value=" ' .$w55_card . ' " readonly/></div></div>';
```